# jquery ui sortable get table tr grouped

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i have some problems with my table i have this table for egs

```
<tr style="">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>item 1</td>
   </tr>

   <tr style="">
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td>item 1.1</td>
   </tr>

   <tr style="">
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>item 1.2</td>
   </tr>

   <tr style="">
        <td>1.1.1</td>
        <td>item 1.1.1</td>
   </tr>
```

i use jquery ui sortable but the problem is that if i want to move the item 1 the item1.2 and item 1.1.1 will also follow something like a group

fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/kN2XL/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kN2XL/ here's the fiddle link

Comment: i think your fiddle link is not working

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [nestedSortable](https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable) to implement this kind of functionality. [Example](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/)

Unfortuately, you will however need to change your html from tables into a hierarchy, like `<ul>` `<li>` etc.

Comment: thank you but i'm looking for tables only, in the fiddle example you'll see also increase and decrease means go under one lever or up one level, i also have to update the ordering when i'm ordering them